# How do I use stereoscopy in IDLE/Python?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, stereoscopy

I have downloaded and installed the stereoscopy library. I know how to execute the program via command line as it shows clearly here: https://pypi.org/project/stereoscopy/#description

However, i looked at its code and I wanted to do it myself. I want to insert the code from: [https://github.com/2sh/StereoscoPy/blob/master/stereoscopy/**init**.py](https://github.com/2sh/StereoscoPy/blob/master/stereoscopy/__init__.py) and see if it works there.

I copied the code and when I run it, nothing happens. No errors or anything, but no picture shows up and no picture is saved.

So I would like to learn how to use this library to make my own anaglyph pictures by coding it myself and not use the command line executable.

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Running StereoscoPy from a command line executes `stereoscopy.__main__`, which mainly consists of

```
from . import _main
_main()
```

`_main` is imported from `_init.py`.  The latter defines some constants, classes, and functions, including `_main`, but does not call any of them.  You need to do what `__main__.py` does, call `_main`, ***after*** stuffing arguments into sys.argv.  One way to do the latter is to use `sys.argv = shlex.split(cli_string, posix=True)` where `cli_string` is the string that would be typed at a command line.

Comment: Hi Terry, I still do not understand what you are trying to tell me. I understand what you mean by doing what _main does but what is sys.argv? and could you explain what the shlex.split line means?

Comment: sys and shlex are standard library modules imported with `import` statement.  Their doc is part of the Library reference.  sys.argv should be covered in the tutorial, but I have not checked.

Comment: Hi Terry, it seemed that what you said didn't work. Is it possible for you to try it and see if it works for you? The code you write should be better and way different to mine. It would mean a lot to me. Thanks Terry!

Comment: Actually, is it possible for me in IDLE, to call up command prompt and insert the stereoscopy command line for it to do itself. therefore, will it work??

Comment: IDLE's Shell simulates standard interactive Python.  Either way, one cannot *directly* run command line programs as a '>>>' prompt.  However, one can run such *indirectly* with the subprocess module.